# What does happen to entire blockchain when a single block modified?

Tags: hash, blockchain

“For example if we tamper a (N-X)th block in blockchain of blocks N. What does happen to N-X+1 block?, as the hash of previous block has changed, will it disconnect with the chain or try to modify and try to rearrange with previous block's hash, and the same for the subsequent blocks (if it is so, what is responsible for self-changing mechanism, is it something like self-evolving block!?)? In this time if a new block has added in to the ledger, will it add as N+1 block as the hash of Nth block remains same.”

Answer (score 0):

Each block has a block header, which contains a reference to the previous block's hash. Since a block's hash is calculated by hashing everything in the block including the header, each block after would have a different hash because their block header would be different.

This would cause all nodes on the network to reject the chain because it doesn't match the chain they already have.